# Translations doesn't show when using 3rd party function WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

so i was trying to organize all translations in one file and then calling function
 `Translations::get(0)`
to retrieve them rather than directly adding
`__('Text here', 'abcd_text_domain')`

so the file for storing translations looks like this:

```
class Translations {

    private static $instance = null;
    private static $translations = [];

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        self::$translations = [
            0 => esc_html__( 'Hello World', 'abcd_text_domain' ),
        ];
        
    }

    /**
     * Returns Instance
     */
    public static function start() {
        if ( self::$instance === null ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get Translation
     * @param int $id Index
     */
    public static function get( int $index ) {
        return isset( self::$translations[$index] ) ? self::$translations[$index] : false;
    }

}
```

after translating the lines as defined above, I am using code below to get the translation on anywhere i want. but its not working instead of translation, its echoing the text above 'Hello World'

```
echo Translations::get(0);
```

but its echoing the correct translation when i directly add below code

```
__('Hello World', 'abcd_text_domain') 
// returns the translation "Hello World in other lang"
```

anyone have any idea why the get function is not working?

**Update:**
the issue is solved. solution is given in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue. had to run the

`Translations::start()`

After loading the plugin text domain. since the esc_html__() was running (in the Translations class constructor) before plugin/theme text domain is loaded, it was not finding it.